# Get day of week from time period

Tags: sql, postgresql, date-arithmetic, generate-series

I have two date from user input. I want to get from jsp these two dates and create a view which shows each day with their own weekday:

```
2013-3-1 MONDAY
2013-3-2 TUESDAY
2013-3-3 WEDNESDAY
```

User inputs date and gives to jsp, say:

```
where start='2013-3-1' and end='2013-3-3'
```

How to do this?

Comment: The term for this sort of operation is "date arithmetic".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select to_char(dt, 'yyyy-mm-dd') as date, to_char(dt, 'Day') as day
from (select ('2013-03-01'::date + i) dt
      from generate_series(0,'2013-03-03'::date - '2013-03-01'::date) as t(i)) as t;
```

You should parameterize the date part of query.

There are a couple of points worth remember in this query.

- date calculation: subtract two date become the number of dates between two dates.
- `generate_series(0, n)` generates 0, 1, ... n

Comment: thanks. how to change the text type to character varying. or vice versa.

Comment: how to change the text type (for date) to date type in the postgresql

Comment: date calculations for `generate_series()` are not necessary. You can use date / timestamp as parameters directly.

Answer (score 1):

This can be simpler:

```
SELECT to_char(d, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS day_txt
     , to_char(d, 'FMDay')      AS weekday
FROM   generate_series('2013-03-01'::date
                     , '2013-03-03'::date
                     , interval '1 day') d;
```

More details under this later question:
[Remove blank-padding from to_char() output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22242202/remove-blank-padding-from-to-char-output/22242593)

Generally it is better to operate with actual [`date` types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html), not with text representations, but I did not understand the details or your requirements.