# Remove blank-padding from to_char() output

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, date-format, generate-series

I generate a view from this:

```
create or replace view datetoday as
select to_char(dt, 'yyyy-mm-dd') as date, to_char(dt, 'Day') as weekday from 
(select ('2013-03-01'::date + i) dt from generate_series(0,'2013-03-03'::date - 2013-03-01'::date) 
as t(i)) as t;
```

It gives me the weekday info as `text` type. Then I use:

```
select date::date, weekday::varchar from datetoday;
```

Now the table is like

```
2013-3-1 Friday
2013-3-2 Saturday
```

If I want to choose the entry:

```
select * from datetoday where weekday='Friday'
```

to change it from `text` to `character varying`.

It seems that the length is fixed is not according to each word length.
For example 'Friday' should have length 6 and Wednesday length 9.
How can I change this, let the length be the actual length of the word?

Because later I will compare this table's `weekday` column to another table's `weekday` column. Like

```
where a.weekday=b.weekday
```

The other weekday is from user from jsp, so the length varies.
Now the length is fixed, the comparison fails.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. Can you show the full SQL and the output from it?

Comment: Instead of to_char(dt, 'Day') why don't you use SELECT EXTRACT(DOW FROM TIMESTAMP dt). This will give you the day of the week number (0 - 6; Sunday is 0). Then you can compare.

Comment: other table is weekday info like Monday not number.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The pattern `'Day'` is blank-padded to the right, making all days 9 characters long. Use the [**`FM`** Template Pattern Modifier](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIMEMOD-TABLE) to remove any padding:

```
SELECT d::date AS day
     , to_char(d, 'yyyy-mm-dd') AS day_text
     , to_char(d, 'FMDay')      AS weekday
FROM generate_series('2013-03-01'::date
                   , '2013-03-07'::date
                   , interval '1 day') d;
```

Also demonstrating [`generate_series()` for timestamps](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-srf.html). One less query level.
If you need an actual `date` in the view, make it an actual type `date`, don't convert to `text` and back.
And don't use the basic type name `date` as column name. Using `day` instead.
And I would just use `text` for the text. No point in converting to `varchar`.