# Trigger for select function

Tags: sql, postgresql, pattern-matching, sql-view

How I can convert this query to trigger:

```
select concat (
    categories.abreviation , '/' ,
    to_char(date_op,'yy'),'/',
    to_char(date_op,'mm'),'/',
    trim(to_char(compteur_op_cat,'000'))
) as num_bord
from
    operation op
    inner join
    categories on categories.id_cat=op.id_cat ;
```

Trigger for table operation, before select return `num_bord` as column.
I need a trigger to concat `num_bord` for some reason:

1. Performance  (note that I have `num_bord` and `num_op` for `concat()` ).
2. Search with `LIKE` easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can simplify your `SELECT`.

```
select concat_ws ('/'
        , c.abreviation
        , to_char(date_op,'yy/mm')
        , to_char(compteur_op_cat, 'FM000')
       ) AS num_bord
from   operation o
join   categories c USING (id_cat);
```

But there are no "triggers on SELECT". You may be looking for a [`VIEW`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createview.html) or a [`MATERIALIZED VIEW`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-creatematerializedview.html).

The key to performance with `LIKE` is indexing:

- [PostgreSQL LIKE query performance variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations/13452528#13452528)

#### Explain

- Use [`concat_ws()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER), since you want to insert separators.
- The `FM` modifier avoids leading spaces for numbers.

  - [Remove blank-padding from to_char() output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22242202/remove-blank-padding-from-to-char-output/22242593#22242593)

Aside: it's *abbreviation*, not <strike>abreviation</strike>.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr.Erwin Brandstetter  for the answer. It is very helpful :)